# AgendaFilter is not working with kie Execution server 7.32 API

Tags: drools, kie, kie-server

I am new to Kie execution server. I uploaded kjar with multiple drl files in execution server and using kie server client api to execute these rules. So far i am able to execute and getting result.

Now i have a requirement of executing the rules which are specified in the filter. I was trying to RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter with the expectation that it is going to execute only rules ending with provided suffix. but when i tried to see the rest request payload generated in kie client api before sending to kie server , it does not have any agenda-filter element inside fireallrule segment.

Even when i tried using the same paylod from postman , by adding this filter manually , it is not even considering that.

So my question is whether this feature is supported using kie rest api call, if yes how to call that from kie server client api.

I am using 7.32 version

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? if so please post it here.